# How to match an object within an image to other images using SURF features (in MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, surf, matlab-cvst

my problem is how to match one image to a set of images and to display the matched images. I am using SURF feature for feature extraction.

Comment: just iterate through all images and compare 1 by 1. Then show the one with the best score.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox, take a look at the following examples:

- [Object Detection In A Cluttered Scene Using Point Feature Matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html)
- [Image Search using Point Features](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-search-using-point-features.html)